# If i partition some space on my G drive for Linux Mint 18, can i add more space later?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I just downloaded Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon (64-bit) and burned it to a dvd. I want to partition about 20GB on my G drive for it, then add more later. the goal is to eventually go over from windows 8 (current operating system) to Linux Mint, is this possible? If not, any better sugestions? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. First dual-boot the system with Linux. Once you are comfortable to get rid of Windows, use Gparted to simply delete Windows partitions and extend the Linux partitions.